# Consulta eloquent, pasar un array a un where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un `array`, `$selectAttribute = ['10', '5']`, necesito obtener mediante una consulta **eloquent** todos los `product_id` que contengan todos los `attribute_id` que tengo en el `array $selectAttribute`. Por ejemplo solo el `product_id` 3 contiene el `attribute_id` 5 y 10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ahora tengo esta consulta, pero con el `whereIn` me traigo todos los `product_id` que contenga al menos un valor del array `$selectAttribute`, yo necesito que solo me de los `product_id` que contengan tanto el `attribute_id` 5 y el 10

```
$product_id = Attribute_product::select('product_id')
                               ->whereIn('attribute_id', $selectAttributes)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Como supongo que esas ids son dinámicas, lo mejor es usar el querybuilder y añadirlas con un for tal que así

```
 $qb = Attribute_product::select('product_id');

        foreach ($selectAttributes as $id){
            $qb->where('attribute_id', $id);
        }

        $product_id = $qb->get();
```

Comment: No me funciona cuando guardo mas de un valor en el array selectAttribute

Comment: Lo acabo de probar por si acaso, y funciona. Podrías poner el error que te da?

Comment: No me sale ningún error, simplemente la consulta me devuelve un array vació

Comment: No tendrás valores que cumplan esa condición

Answer (score 1):

el whereIn lo que hace es obtener los resultados que coinciden con los atributos pasados en el array,por lo tanto, es normal que te de todos los que contienen al menos un valor de los pasados por el array $selectAttribute.

En caso de querer que solo coja los datos que sean 5 y 10 la consulta creo que quedaría mas o menos así.

```
$product_id = Attribute_product::select('product_id') ->where('attribute_id','5')->where('attribute_id','10')->get();
```

ya que la concatenación de varios where por defecto en una consulta equivale a la expresión lógica AND espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: Los valores del array selectAttribute son dinamicos, van cambiando

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez no sea el modo mas eficiente pero se me ocurre de este modo:

- Declarar el `array` que contiene los valores dinámicos:

Código:

```
 $selectAttribute = ['10', '5'];
```

- Construimos la consulta por medio del método `whereIn` que nos acepta un array de valores para la búsqueda y filtrado

Código:

```
$consulta = Attribute_product::select('product_id')
                          ->whereIn('attribute_id', [selectAttribute[0], selectAttribute[1]])->get();
```

De modo tal que le pasamos dentro del array de valores que pide dicho método, las 2 posiciones que ocupa el `array` externo `selectAttribute` y solo indicando sus posiciones **(0, 1)** entonces así lo mantenemos dinámico pues aunque cambien los valores, nosotros solo estamos requiriendo los a través de sus índices.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una manera para hacerlo con where.

```
$qb = Attribute_product::select('product_id')
  ->where(function ($query) use ($selectAttributes) {
      foreach ($selectAttributes as $id) {
          $query->where('attribute_id', '=', $id);
      }
  })
  ->get();
```

Sección **Advanced Wheres** de la documentación oficial de **Laravel**
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres

Answer (score 1):

Hola Tuve un aso similar he probado tu procedimiento con mis entidades y atributo y funciona perfecto, sólo debes quitar los indices ya que sion valores que traes de tu base de datos y si por algun momento tus registros crecen y ya no tienes los indices [0] y [1], sino [0], [1], [2], como lo harías?

Yo lo hice así y ha funcionado;
$selectAttribute = ['10', '5']; //En mi Caso estos datos viene de mi Base de datos asi;
$selectAttribute = $request->ids; // [1, 2]

$consulta = Attribute_product::select('product_id')
->whereIn('attribute_id', $selectAttribute)->get();

Espero sea de utilidad. Saludos.